# Data export cut-off beyond 1,012,486 features

Tags: r, python-3.x, arcgis

I am using python to export a CSV from a shapefile highlighting addresses. I want to use these data in R to measure environmental exposures.

Here is my code for ArcPY:

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(
in_rows = os.path.join("addresses.shp"),
out_path = os.path.join(directory),
out_name= 'addresses' + '.csv')
```

The shapefile has around 1.4 million features in it. There are 16 fields, including FID.

I read the table into R after it was exported. Unfortunately, all features after the 1,012,486 are given field values equal to the feature with FID = 1,012,486.

Why is this happening? Are there any workarounds that don't require breaking up the shapefile into multiple files?

Comment: Just to double check: Are the lines in CSV are differing from each other after line 1,012,486 ?

Comment: Yes, they are! They represent different individuals. When I brought the data into R, I tab'd the individuals by year of birth and came up with 3x as many births in 2011 than in the previous eight years. This clued me into the fact that all obversations after the 1,012,486 were automatically given a birth year of 2011 (despite having actually been borne between 2011 and 2014).

Comment: How many columns do you have per row? Does the same happen with smaller number of columns?